# Is Mathematica, while operating within $MachinePrecision IEEE 754 compliant?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I was looking in Mathematicas documentation and could not find to which point Mathematica includes the IEEE 754 standard?

It is mention it in its documentation [MachinePrecision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html) under Background & Context:

> floating-point computation and is most commonly implemented using the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754) standard

and has an entry in *Mathworld* [IEEE 754-2008](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IEEE754-2008.html):

> As of 2014, the IEEE 754-2008 is the most commonly implemented standard for floating-point arithmetic. This framework is a massive overhaul of its predecessor IEEE 754-1985 and includes a built-in collection of guidelines specifying nearly every conceivable aspect of floating-point theory.

Of course Mathematica is aware of the standard, but I could not find a single passage where they explicitly mentioned the implementation of the **IEEE 754**?

---

P.S. I am using Mathematica for the unit testing of a C++ program and feel want to be sure I can reproduce the same results within both programs.

Comment: Also worthwhile mentioning is that specifying `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` just gives the same precision as IEEE754 doubles but is still computed with an arbitrary precision number implementation while `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` actually uses hardware machine precision numbers, which makes it usually much faster but also inherits all the quirks from IEEE 754.

Comment: Machine precision and IEEE 754 is discussed in the documentation for [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html), 3rd para. under "Background and Context."  [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision.html) is just a constant, "[typically] `53Log[10,2]`,"  the precision of the [**binary64**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) floating-point format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mathematica* doesn't implement IEEE 754. **Machine numbers** use the native arithmetic of the hardware, which is usually IEEE 754. For approximate numbers of arbitrary precision, *Mathematica* uses its own arithmetic, not IEEE 754. Numbers with precision `$MachinePrecision` are not necessarily machine numbers: they may have arbitrary precision that happens to match `$MachinePrecision`.